# calling say function in perl 5.18

Tags: perl

To call the say function in perl < 6
you can call either `CORE::say` or first declare using `use feature 'say`

are there other alternatives ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I recommend to use the documentation. It is much better than you might expect.

Calling `perldoc -f say` gives:

> This keyword is available only when the "say" feature is enabled; see feature.  Alternately, include a "use v5.10" or later to the current scope.

So this gives you at least one more way to make it available.

Also, if you look at the documentation of feature (`perldoc feature`) you will find more ways to enable features, other than just enabling each feature separately:

> - By using the "-E" switch on the command-line instead of "-e"....
> - By requiring explicitly a minimal Perl version number for your program, with the "use VERSION" construct....

Also see the section about FEATURE BUNDLES.

Comment: is there any way besides using core:: ? and doesn't use anything ?

Comment: @himanshukela: I'm not sure what you expect. Some magic switch which does not work the way all the other switches work? Please be more specific and maybe describe what your real problem is.

Comment: is there any keyword x, such that x::say would work, like CORE::say?

Comment: No, why should it be? You already have CORE? But of course you could define your own package which does this - but then you have to `use` it.

Comment: just asking is there an alternative ? other namepsace than core which has it ?

Comment: No, I don't think so. While the motto is "There is more than one way to do it" the motto is not "There are more than 3 ways to do it" :) And again, if you would want to use another namespace which defines it you have to `use this_namespace` somewhere.

Comment: @himanshukela: `CORE` isn't a real namespace (package) at all. It's just a way of explicitly saying you want the core operator instead of some other subroutine whose name may clash.